# MongoDB, BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, bson

I am doing my projects with no errors, but suddenly server-side crashes and the error is "BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer"

I have tried other suggestions for this similar problem from StackOverflow but it's not working.

I have attached-
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

but not solved yet. The full error of code is

```
var _this = _super.call(this, message) || this;
                           ^

BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
    at new BSONTypeError (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
    at new ObjectId (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:66:23)
    at ObjectId (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:26:20)
    at F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\index.js:107:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at param (F:\Web Development\Projects\Fiverr\hridayshaha\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

index.js:107:24 --- `console.log(id);`

from line 105

```
        app.get('/events/:id', async(req, res) =>{
        const id = req.params.id;
        console.log(id);
        const query = {_id: ObjectId(id)};
        const items = await eventsCollection.findOne(query);
        res.json(items);
```

Comment: So what happens on line 107 of `server/index.js`?

Comment: line 105: app.get('/events/:id', async(req, res) =>{
   line 106:const id = req.params.id;
   line 107: console.log(id);
   const query = {_id: ObjectId(id)};
   const items = await eventsCollection.findOne(query);
   res.json(items);
  })--- I don't know what heppens, everything is wroking fine but when I want to fetch data it crashes.

Comment: Please add that code to your question instead of posting it in a comment.

Comment: ok I am editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no input validation in your code, but you cannot assume that `req.params.id` always is a valid `ObjectId`.

You can modify the route path to make sure that the route handler only accepts something that looks like a valid `ObjectId`:

```
app.get('/events/:id([0-9a-fA-F]{24})', async (req, res) => { … });
```

Documented [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters).

Comment: thank you it's working but I have done the same process in my past projects, never used 'id([0-9a-fA-F]{24})' but works totally fine even in this project also working, it crashes suddenly what's the resson.?

Comment: @Hosen very likely someone/something requesting `/events/XXX` without a valid id. Perhaps to "test" your server, perhaps out of mistake, who knows :D

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, just make sure that when you query the database be specific.
instead of findByIdAndUpdate use findOneAndUpdate, if you intend on using findByIdAndUpdate make sure that you indeed use the id and nothing else. The whole issue with the id stuff is that you are querying for the id, and yet you are most likely using an email to perform the actual querying.